# Error when execute php artisan migrate in laravel console

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to execute `php artisan migrate`, I get the following:

> In `Connection.php` line 647: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>   (SQL: `select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema =
>   cotacao_job and table_name = migrations`)
>
> APP_NAME=Laravel APP_ENV=local
>   APP_KEY=base64:Ciz4TWDongGPodaNDo9wcxJh48A/af6JwWWE3/ydPkI=
>   APP_DEBUG=true APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
>   APP_URL=http://localhost/work-cotation-service/
>
> DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=33060 // I`ve tried 3360
>   too DB_DATABASE=homestead DB_USERNAME=homestead DB_PASSWORD=secret
>
> BROADCAST_DRIVER=log CACHE_DRIVER=file SESSION_DRIVER=file
>   SESSION_LIFETIME=120 QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
>
> REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 REDIS_PASSWORD=null REDIS_PORT=6379
>
> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io MAIL_PORT=2525
>   MAIL_USERNAME=null MAIL_PASSWORD=null

its in a new homestead 5.1

Answer (score 2):

When you are using homestead than you need to run these command in a vagrant box after ssh, not in the normal console
to simply just follow these steps.

```
 1. ssh into your homestead using below command 
 2. cd ~homestead (where you set up your virtual box)
 3. vagrant up
 4. vagrant ssh
 5. cd Code/PATH_TO_YOUR_APP_ROOT_DIR
 6. php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure the connection to the database in the `.env` file or `config/database.php` if you don't use `.env`

Comment: I did that. but it seems doesnt work. I`ll add my env file in the description

Comment: @user536638 First create DB. and add your name DB, USER and Password - `DB_DATABASE=[you DB]
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=`

Comment: @user536638 if i help you, chek my answer

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem occur just because you are not setting up the database detail in the .env file so kindly update it or else you can also configure it by update the details in config/database.php

For .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```